# AngularJS and HTML: Escaping quotes inside a variable for an onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i'm just wondering how to escape a function if it has quotes inside.
for example, my variable is:

```
   {{ video.Id }} = "Don't";
```

then if my markup in html is like this:

```
    <button ng-click="executeFunc('{{video.Id}}')"/>
```

I will have an error saying that I have unterminated quotes. (Coming from the variable that have quotes inside.) Any help would be appreciated! thank you

Comment: is this `{{ video.Id }} = "Don't";` actually written somewhere in your code? it looks very strange (because the {{scopeVariable}} notation is usually used in views to access variables, rather than to set them, and anyway the `=` would need to be within the `{{}}` as well!)

Comment: just an example. basically that video.Id is equal to a variable that has a quotation in it. and i get an error from angular saying that i have unterminated quotes, obviously coming from that particular variable. i don't know how to escape it so that angular will accept the variable and at the same time keep the quotation mark inside that variable

Comment: Where is the variable being set though - in the html template or in your controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the inner {{}}, just do `<button ng-click="executeFunc(video.Id)"/>`

Your controller function, `executeFunc` will get the proper value.

Comment: I still get the error, what happens is that when it is already defined in the javascript like so, i get the error: `Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 93-95 [')] in expression [executeFunc('Don't')]` what puzzles me is how to be able to escape the quotes in the variable

Comment: Must be something else you're doing that I can't see from the code. I tested it and it works fine. Here is a plnkr showing that it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/rm6lTpGvf95bMV0r5oWC

Comment: nope you're totally right man, removed the double curlies and the single quotes and it works fine now, it still shows an error but nonetheless, it works. cheers!

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. I tried something like this: `<button ng-click="executeFunc('video.Id')"/>`  note the single quotes around the variable

Comment: A point to be noted: Even though you use `executeFunc(video.Id)` and it works fine, when the page loads and you inspect the ng-click value, you will find that it will still be `executeFunc(video.Id)` and it won't show up as `executeFunc(Don't)` i.e. it won't parse the variable value and show it in the HTML markup, but for programming needs, it does parse and read the variable value correctly.