# How do I deal with quotes when calling a method from an AngularJS template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in Employees" class="gridRow" style="min-height:25px;">
  <td ng-click="showDeleteEmployeeDialog('{{employee.Id}}');"><img src="Images/delete.png" style="width:24px; height:24px; cursor:pointer;" /></td>
```

`{{employee.Id}}` ends up getting evaluated as literal text.
I want it to call `showDeleteEmployeeDialog()` and pass in the `employeeId`.
How do I do this?

Comment: Please elaborate your question... You want to use it in HTML or JavaScript?

Comment: You will need do it inside a ng-repeat loop, passing it through your function: showDeleteEmployeeDialog(employee.id)

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. I found the answer here:
[AngularJS and HTML: Escaping quotes inside a variable for an onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525078/angularjs-and-html-escaping-quotes-inside-a-variable-for-an-onclick-function)

Apparently, the quotes and the curly braces should be left out.
ng-click="showDeleteEmployeeDialog(employee.Id);"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting